# Parameter expansion in variable assigned with a wildcard

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, variable

I have two files in my current folder (MA502) whose names are -

```
MA502_TAAGGCGA-TCGCAGG_L001_R1_001.at.fastq
MA502_TAAGGCGA-TCGCAGG_L001_R2_001.at.fastq
```

I have many such folders - ex MA503, MA504 etc, and I want to loop over those.

I assign my variable names using wild cards -

```
Forward=*R1*.at.fastq
Reverse=*R2*.at.fastq
```

I want to process these files in a script, and I want my output to replace `.at` to `.atqt`, so that the final name would look like -

```
MA502_TAAGGCGA-TCGCAGG_L001_R1_001.atqt.fastq
MA502_TAAGGCGA-TCGCAGG_L001_R2_001.atqt.fastq
```

I tried

```
awk 'script' $Forward > ${Forward/.at/.atqt}
```

My final file name looks like -

```
*R1*.atqt.fastq
```

instead of my expectation which was

```
MA502_TAAGGCGA-TCGCAGG_L001_R1_001.atqt.fastq
```

I've learnt everything by necessity on unix, so I'm not sure how variable names are processed. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 16):

The command `Forward=*R1*.at.fastq` sets the variable `Forward` to the string `*R1*.at.fastq` (star, capital R, digit 1, star, dot, lowercase A, etc.). Wildcards are only expanded in contexts that allow multiple words; the right-hand size of a variable assignment expects a single word, so no wildcard expansion occurs.

In a command like `cat $Forward`, the wildcards in the value of `Forward` are expanded. When a variable is expanded outside double quotes, its value is intepreted as a whitespace-delimited list of wildcard patterns, and if any pattern matches one or more files, it's replaced by the list of files.

In `${Forward/.at/.atqt}`, first the variable's value is looked up: `*R1*.at.fastq`. Then the text substitution is applied to this string, yielding `*R1*.atqt.fastq`. The result is an unquoted variable expansion so it is interpreted as a wildcard pattern. But `*R1*.atqt.fastq` doesn't match any file, so it's left unchanged.

To expand the wildcard when setting `Forward`, you could make it an array.

```
Forward=(*R1*.at.fastq)
```

This sets `Forward` to a 1-element array, the element being the string `MA502_TAAGGCGA-TCGCAGG_L001_R1_001.at.fastq`. The wildcard pattern is expanded to the list of matches because it's in a context (the parentheses of array assignment) where multiple words are expected.

In bash, `$Forward` when `Forward` is an array is equivalent to `${Forward[0]}` — referencing an array variable with the same syntax as a scalar variable refers to the first element of the array. So you can leave your awk command unchanged.